# Visual Studio vs Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, computer-science, game-development

I'm a Computer Science student and I'm learning to become a game developer. For the last 1 year, I've been using Visual Studio to edit my scripts in Unity. It was only recently that my colleagues shared with me about Visual Studio Code. I don't really know the differences between the two and which one is better for me as a computer science student and as a game developer?

Comment: If you want your app to run on different OS, I have the feeling that VS code is better. But I would like to share my experience with VS Code: I'm working mainly with C++ and C# code on Windows. When I first tried to use VS Code, I had the feeling to be (a long way) back in time compared with VS2019. Everything seems to be over-complicated, user unfriendly. On the over side, VS2019 (and previous versions too) is so easy to use. I don't like VS Code at all . May be I did not find a good tutorial about it, may be I'm a dumb, and may be it's a great product, but I will stick to vs2019 for now.

Comment: I think VS Code is doing pretty well compared to 40GB Visual Studio IDE which makes your system to crawl. Not everybody is sitting behind a $2000 machine.