# No templates on Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio, new-project

So, I am trying to follow along with a video in order to help myself with a project I have soon. When following this project I recognize that my visual studios is different. In the video it shows a `"create a new project"` window along with different templates like `"Console App"` and `"ASP.NET core web app"`. While on mine, I am not able to see any templates. I have tried looking up other ways to find these templates, but I have yet to find it. I am hoping someone can help me figure out what I am missing on my visual studios. Below is the video visual studios and the second picture is my visual studios(`macbook`).

Video Visual Studios:
[image]

My Visual Studios:
[image]

Comment: You are confusing Visual Studio with Visual Studio Code. The two are not the same, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371560/visual-studio-vs-visual-studio-code) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you failed the download. The video you're watching is using Visual studio, but you are using Visual Studio Code. You should change and download Visual studio.